# how to build form of multiple models in yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to create a form that use multiple model instances and submit them all at once **(tabular input)**, i have read this [article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/666/handling-tabular-data-loading-and-validation-in-yii-2/)  on wiki `yiiframework` , but what i am trying to do is to build a custom model that contains properties and attributes from multiple models then use this model in my form.

**[Example]**

**model1**

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Country extends ActiveRecord
{
   ........
}
```

**molel2**

```
 namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord
{
   ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own model is simple. The more detailed explanation could be found by following [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html).

Your own model might look like this:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class Custom extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $surname;
    public $email;
    public $country;
    public $city;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
        // the name, surname, city attributes are required
        [['name', 'surname', 'country', 'city'], 'required'],

        // the email attribute should be a valid email address
        ['email', 'email'],
    ];
    }

    public function customFunction()
    {
        //some custom things
    }
}
```

Comment: What about saving and validating attributes ?

Comment: The validation rules are declared in rules() function. You may call `yii\base\Model::validate()` to validate the received data.  If no error is found, it will return true. Otherwise, it will keep the errors in the `yii\base\Model::$errors` property and return false.

Comment: Saving is just `$model->save()`
It will be usually called in controller:
`if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }`